# How to assign indexVar value to custom field in Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a scenario where i've created a table and using drag and drop functionality. So from here if i'm dragging row from its position to any other position it should reflect there index value and this index value must assign to custom field of an object.

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="dynamicListController">
    <aura:attribute name="objName" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="objFields" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="ContactData" type="dynamicListController.Contactwrap"/>
    <aura:attribute name="indx" type="String" />

    <div class="slds-page-header">
        <div class="slds-media">
            <div class="slds-media__figure">
                <span class="slds-icon_container" title="Description of icon when needed">
                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:kanban" variant="base" size="small"/>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-media__body">
                <h1 class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate slds-align-middle" title="Contact Records">Contact Records</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:0.5rem;">
        <div class="stageContainer" style="width:100%">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Contact LastName">Last Name</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Contact FirstName">First Name</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Contact Phone">Phone</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Contact Index" aura:id="indexval">Index</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead> 
                <tbody ondrop="{!c.drop}" ondragover="{!c.allowDrop}" >
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.ContactData.records}" var="objRecord" indexVar="index">
                        <tr draggable="true" ondragstart="{!c.drag}" id="{!objRecord.Id}">
                            <td data-label="Last Name">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!objRecord.LastName}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="First Name">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!objRecord.FirstName}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Phone">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!objRecord.Phone}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Index">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!objRecord.Index__c}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </table> 
        
        </div>    
    </div>   
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    
        var action = component.get("c.getContactwrap");
        
        action.setParams({
            "objName":component.get("v.objName"),
            "objFields":component.get("v.objFields")
        });
        
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.dir(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.ContactData", response.getReturnValue());
            } 
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    
    doView: function(component, event, helper) {
        var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        editRecordEvent.setParams({
            "recordId": event.target.id
        });
        editRecordEvent.fire();
    },
    
    allowDrop: function(component, event, helper) {
        event.preventDefault();
    },
    
    drag: function (component, event, helper) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
    },
    
    drop: function (component, event, helper) {
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        // Find the record ID by crawling up the DOM hierarchy
        var tar = event.target.closest('[id]');
        var contactData = component.get("v.ContactData");
        var index1, index2, temp;
        // Find the index of each item to move
        contactData.records.forEach((v,i)=>{if(v.Id===data) index1 = i; if(v.Id===tar.id) index2 = i;});
        var indxv = index2;
        console.log(indxv);
        if(index1<index2) {
            // Lower index to higher index; we move the lower index first, then remove it.
            contactData.records.splice(index2+1, 0, contactData.records[index1]);
            contactData.records.splice(index1, 1);

        } else {
            // Higher index to lower index; we remove the higher index, then add it to the lower index.
            temp = contactData.records.splice(index1, 1)[0];
            contactData.records.splice(index2, 0, temp);

        }
        // Trigger aura:valueChange, component will rerender
        component.set("v.ContactData", contactData);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. Could you please show the code snippet of your solution?

Comment: Yes, uploaded component and controller

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/fb13ac4781c79fad6495ef7dc1676f4f) that does this. The trick is that you use an attribute like `data-drag-id="{!index}"`. You can then read that attribute in your handlers.

Comment: Thanx for your reply @sfdcfox, but my 2nd question is not resolved that how can I save/assign index value to custom field of an object.